# How to Redirect to different pages using branch in Oracle Apex?

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

I have defined a function returning a URL(redirect).

[branch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qr8yn.png)

**Page 1: Home-
Pre-Rendering-
Before Header-
Branches**

**With the following script:**

```
declare
  x number:=1;
  myurl varchar2(255);
begin
  if v('AGENCY') = 'R-AG' then
     x := 3; 
     myurl := 'f?p=&APP_ID.:3:&SESSION.'; ---page 3
  else
     x := 50; 
     myurl := 'f?p=&APP_ID.:50:&SESSION.'; --- page 50
  end if;
  return myurl;
end;
```

**I have defined item applications**

1. Name : AGENCY
2. Scope : Application
3. Session State Protection: Unrestricted

**I have defined an application computation**

1. Sequence :10
2. Computation Item: AGENCY
3. Computacion Point: After
4. Authentication Computacion Type: SQL Query(return single value)
5. Computacion:

   SELECT ROL
   FROM USERS;

***But for some reason the branch only took page 3 as priority and "else" is not fulfilled to redirect to page 50 when it is the case.***

Answer (score 0):

Your computation looks like something that should have a filter - how many rows return from a select from 'users' with no filter?
Though if there were any issues from that, I would have thought p50 would be the result.

You could also do this more declaratively. As in, have a branch to page 3 when item AGENCY = R-AG, and a second branch to p50 with no condition.

You first branch to p3 could also have just a query returning rows, such as

```
select null
from users
where username = :app_user -- or whatever your filter should probably be here
and rol = 'R-AG'
```